# Cyclotomic polynomial, after adjoining a radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-polynomials

Suppose that $p>2$ is prime and that $a$ is a rational number for which $\sqrt[p]{a}$ is in $\mathbb C\backslash\mathbb Q$.

The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_p$ is well-known to be irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.  Is it also irreducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{a})$?

I believe this is true.

I was able to argue it partially by contradiction, after assuming that $\Phi_p(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{a})$.  I say "partially" because my particular argument only works when I assume that the roots of $f$ do not consist of pairs of multiplicative inverses in the group of $p$-th roots of unity.  (So for example, my argument works when the degrees of $f$ and $g$ are odd, but may fail when the degrees are even.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I do not wish to use the order of the Galois group as part of the argument.

Comment: Hint: Let $\zeta$ be one of the zeros of $\Phi_p$. Then $[\Bbb{Q}(\zeta):\Bbb{Q}]=p-1$ which is coprime to $[\Bbb{Q}(\root p\of a):\Bbb{Q}]$. Therefore  $[\Bbb{Q}(\zeta,\root p\of a):\Bbb{Q}]=$____. Therefore the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\root p\of a)$ is ____

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Thanks.  For this, I need to know that $x^p-a$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ when $x^p-a$ has no roots in $\mathbb Q$.  Is there a quick way to see this?

Comment: If you know Galois theory, it is easy to see that $x^p-a$, considered over $Q(\zeta)$, splits in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[p]{a})$, its roots being $\sqrt[p]{a}$, $\zeta \sqrt[p]{a}$, $\zeta^2 \sqrt[p]{a}$, $\ldots$ $\zeta^{p-1} \sqrt[p]{a}$.  It is also easy to check that the automorphism that sends $\sqrt[p]{a}$ to $\zeta \sqrt[p]{a}$ and fixes $\zeta$ has order $p$.  Thus, the extension has order $p$ and so $x^p - a$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, hence also over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If some prime divides $a$ only to the first power, it is easier just to check that $x^p - a$ meets the Eisenstein irreducibility criterion.

Comment: @BarrySmith: Thanks.  Like I said in the question, I don't want to use the Galois group.  Is there actually a way to use Eisenstein to show the irreducibility of $x^p-a$?  All the arguments I have seen use the field norm.  If we take the polynomial to be primitive, we just want the p-th power of $a$ to not be in $\mathbb Z$.  But surely you can find such an $a$ that is also divisible by the square of a prime.  For instance, $x^4-4$.

Comment: In the argument I gave, it was a different Galois group than the one for the cyclotomic extension -- it wasn't clear to me that you don't want to use the order of *any* Galois group.  Why don't you want to use the order of a Galois group? I would think any other argument would be messier.

Comment: Yes, the Eisenstein argument doesn't always work, which is why I gave it only as a second option when that works for certain $a$.

Comment: Irreducibility of $x^p-a$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is not difficult, because you know its zeros. If $f(x)$ is a factor of degree $m$, then its constant term is the product of zeros of $f$, i.e. $a^{m/p}$ times a root of unity. How could that be rational?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : That was essentially my argument for irreducibility of $\Phi_p$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[p]{a})$, i.e. if $\Phi_p(x)=f(x)g(x)$, then the constant term of $f(x)$ must be a p-th root of unity.  But it could be $1$ itself, if the roots of $f(x)$ consist of pairs of inverses from the group of p-th roots of unity.  Do you see a way to recover this argument?

Comment: It makes a world of difference, when we are looking at factors of $x^p-a$ instead of $\Phi_p(x)$. We have that extra $a^{m/p}$ in there.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Out of our discussions, I think I can build an appropriate proof of what I was after in the original questions (and without using orders of Galois groups).  Just one silly question: how do I absolutely know that if $\sqrt[p]{a}$ is irrational, then $(\sqrt[p]{a})^m e^{2k\pi i/p}$ is irrational too, for all $k$ and for all $1\leq m\leq p-1$?  I'm sure this is trivial, and it seems about as reasonable as anything, but for some reason I just can't convince myself that it would true beyond in every possible case.

Comment: That's the idea! Use the uniqueness of integer factorization of both the numerator and the denominator of $a$.